# Smart contract, that sends all the ETH to a certain wallet if balance is greater than 0

Tags: tokens, ether, gas

I'm new to Smart Contracts and I'm trying to build a simple Smart Contract, which sends all the ETH to a certain address if the balance gets greater than 0. I hope you can give me an example contract. :)

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract TestContract {
    address public ethReceiver = <YOUR_RECEIVER_ADDRESS>;

    receive() payable external {
        payable(ethReceiver).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```